# Eclipse not recognizing files from SourceTree

Tags: java, eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

My partner made a BitBucket git repository, and uploaded a Java project from Eclipse via SourceTree. I made my own project in Eclipse on my computer, and using SourceTree I pulled all the files from BitBucket. While these files show in Windows Explorer, they don't show in the Eclipse workspace. Is there a way to continue using SourceTree and Eclipse without using EGit, or is there no solution?

Answer (score 0):

Could be because `.classpath` and `.project` files are registered in `.gitignore` so they didn't get checked in to git (that is right as well)

Your eclipse needs to regenerate those file based on your project type